# Is there a library function or operator to create a tuple?

Tags: f#

Given a string of digits, I would like to have a sequence of tuples mapping the non-zero characters with their position in the string.  Example:

```
IN: "000140201"
OUT: { (3, '1'); (4, '4'); (6, '2'); (8, '1') }
```

Solution:

```
let tuples = source
             |> Seq.mapi (fun i -> fun c -> (i, c))
             |> Seq.filter (snd >> (<>) '0')
```

It seems like `(fun i -> fun c -> (i, c))` is a lot more typing than it should be for such a simple and presumably common operation.  It's easy to declare the necessary function:

```
let makeTuple a b = (a, b)
let tuples2 = source
              |> Seq.mapi makeTuple
              |> Seq.filter (snd >> (<>) '0')
```

But it seems to me that if the library provides the `snd` function, it should also provide the `makeTuple` function (and probably with a shorter name), or at least it should be relatively easy to compose.  I couldn't find it; am I missing something?  I tried to build something with the framework's Tuple.Create, but I couldn't figure out how to get anything other than the single-argument overload.

Comment: Minor improvement `Seq.mapi (fun a b -> a,b)`

Comment: @JohnPalmer ah, thanks.  I thought I had an error with that syntax earlier, but I suppose the error was caused by something else.

Comment: Also, `||>` is the reverse of the operator that you want.

Comment: As a workaround, replace `Seq.mapi` with `Seq.zip (Seq.initInfinite id)`

Comment: another approach is to use a list comprehension, e.g. ``[for i=0 to xs.Length-1 do if xs.[i]<>'0' then yield i,xs.[i]]``

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> But it seems to me that if the library provides the snd function, it should also provide the makeTuple function.

F# assumes that you decompose tuples (using `fst`, `snd`) much more often than composing them. Functional library design often follows *minimal* principle. Just provide functions for common use cases, other functions should be easy to define.

> I couldn't find it; am I missing something?

No, you aren't. It's the same reason that [FSharpPlus](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus/) has defined `tuple2`, `tuple3`, etc. Here are utility functions straight from [Operators](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus/blob/600f538b4caef97f3159094cb0e34b2215871fef/src/FSharpPlus/Operators.fs#L35-35):

```
/// Creates a pair
let inline tuple2 a b = a,b
/// Creates a 3-tuple
let inline tuple3 a b c = a,b,c
/// Creates a 4-tuple
let inline tuple4 a b c d = a,b,c,d
/// Creates a 5-tuple
let inline tuple5 a b c d e = a,b,c,d,e
/// Creates a 6-tuple
let inline tuple6 a b c d e f = a,b,c,d,e,f
```

> I tried to build something with the framework's Tuple.Create, but I couldn't figure out how to get anything other than the single-argument overload.

F# compiler hides properties of `System.Tuple<'T1, 'T2>` to enforce pattern matching idiom on tuples. See [Extension methods for F# tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115260/extension-methods-for-f-tuples) for more details.

*That said, point-free style is not always recommended in F#. If you like point-free, you have to do a bit of heavy lifting yourself.*

Answer (score 5):

The @pad's answer is great, just to add my 2 cents: I am using similar operator

```
let inline (-&-) a b = (a, b)
```

and it looks very convenient to write `let x = a -&- b`

Maybe you'll find this operator useful too

Comment: In that simple case I'd prefer to use `let x = a, b`. Note that the parenthesis is not necessary in this case.